# Check if internal (nested) MySQL query returned a value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM block_list WHERE client=123
```

which is nested within

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE (client=123 AND product=234)
  AND 1 <> (SELECT 1 FROM block_list WHERE client=123)
```

It works (other way round) if I replace `<>` with `=`. But I want it to return NO records if the user is in the blocked list. Block is temporary and affects only some parts of the website.

Is tehre a way to check if nested query returned **no results** within WHERE clause?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. `NOT EXISTS`.  Replace `AND 1 <> (SELECT...)` with `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE
    client=123
    AND product=234
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM block_list WHERE client=123)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    products 
WHERE 
    client = 123 AND 
    product = 234 AND (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM block_list 
        WHERE client = 123
        LIMIT 1
    ) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it's a good application of a join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM products p
JOIN block_list b USING (client)
WHERE b.client=123 AND p.product=234
```

Answer (score 0):

For readability/maintainability, I'd suggest splitting the `block_list` query into its own separate query *before* selecting the products. There's no reason to over-complicate the logic of single queries like this.

If the client is in the block list, then your original query design is for no results to be returned. Why even perform the query?

```
$rs = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM block_list WHERE client = 123');
if($rs->rowcount() == 0 ) {
  $rs = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE client = 123 AND product = 234');
  // more code!
}
```